# Max n threads in code block

Tags: c#, multithreading

How do i run max n threads in a c# code block?

I'll like something easy and short like this pseudocode

```
lock (this, 5)
{
   //do some work
}
```

EDIT: This is not a shared memory, race condition thing. The problem is that I have alot of threads. But I found out the a resource used in one part of the code is failing when used too much in parallel. I could use a objecpool, but I hoped i could do it even more easy.

Comment: "what is a semaphore?"

Comment: "why should I avoid locking `this`?"

Comment: You're effectively saying "start a huge number of threads and make them wait in line to perform *some work*". Are you sure that's what you want to achieve?

Comment: The shared resource should do the managment of parallel users and determine the number of parallel users - not the callers - good luck in adapting every caller when you make changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)

> Limits the number of threads that can
>   access a resource or pool of resources
>   concurrently.

Comment: I see Semaphore is the solution. Too bad the readability is low

Answer (score 0):

you could use a ThreadPool instead which allow you to set up the min/max number of thread

have a llok at the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx

you should avoid to lock (this) because you risk to have dead-locking. The looking should be as much granula as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the lock as such, because this marks a critical section for single execution only. You will need to use your own semaphores, I think, along these lines ( not code - just concept )

> var semaphore
>
> semaphore.flag 5 times
>
> semaphore.wait
>
> do code
>
> semaphore.flag

I would say that if you are going to use this, you need to understand what you are doing and how it works. However, it is the mechanism that lock uses, so you should achieve what is needed.

Comment: I see Semaphore is the solution. Too bad the readability is low.

Comment: You could package up your semaphore code so that you can make the calls within this code more readable, very much as you want. Which would make it easy to apply if anything else needed this too.

Answer (score 0):

I also think a semaphore is what you're looking for. In .NET 4.0, however, there might be another way for you as well. If you like 5 threads to run the same code concurrently, you could put it into a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and use a [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) to make .NET spawn at most 5 threads. Just set the [`MaximumConcurrencyLevel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.maximumconcurrencylevel.aspx) property.

This does not do any semaphore-like thinks, so other threads might enter into the section too! See also [Task Parallel Library (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for more information.